# Join the first 3 records in each group, and merge as one row

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

One `user` has many `qualifications`. I need to produce a **spreadsheet in Excel** from a MySQL database. The result should contain a row for each user, with columns for their 1st, 2nd and 3rd qualifications on the same row.

**Users Table**

```
id  |  Name     
--------------
1   |  James
2   |  Bob
3   |  Adam
4   |  Michael
```

**Qualifications Table**

```
id  |  user_id  |  subject
-----------------------------------------
1   |  1        |  English
2   |  2        |  History
3   |  2        |  Mathematics
4   |  2        |  Biology
5   |  2        |  Sports Science
6   |  2        |  Art
7   |  3        |  Physics
8   |  3        |  Chemistry
10  |  4        |  Geography
11  |  4        |  Computer Science
12  |  4        |  Theology
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
User ID  |  Name     |  Qualification 1  |  Qualification 2   |  Qualification 3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |  James    |  English          |  NULL              |  NULL
2        |  Bob      |  History          |  Mathematics       |  Biology
3        |  Adam     |  Physics          |  Chemistry         |  NULL
4        |  Michael  |  Geography        |  Computer Science  |  Theology
```

---

**Notes**

- I only need the first 3 qualifications for each user.
- The user could have any number of qualifications. They may have none, they may have 10.
- In the example, James only has 1 qualification. Bob has 5. Adam only has 2.
- I only need a SQL solution, but the end goal is to export to Excel (not relevant unless there is something I can leverage in Excel to make this simpler).
- This is a one-time task. I won't need to do this regularly.

Comment: If you are building a csv, you could also use group_concat with a ',' between fields to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method (pre-MySQL 8.0) uses variables and conditional aggregation:

```
select u.user_id, u.name,
       max(case when rn = 1 then q.subject end) as qualification_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then q.subject end) as qualification_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then q.subject end) as qualification_3
from users u left join
     (select q.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = q.user_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := q.user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from qualifications q,
           (select @u := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by q.user_id, q.id
     ) q
     on u.id = q.user_id
where rn <= 3
group by u.id, u.name
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting an error at `(select @u := -1, @rn := 0) params` due to missing comma I think (correct me if I'm wrong). I think I can work with this from here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions. The three subjects could appear in one column:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(qualifications.subject SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) AS subjects
FROM users
LEFT JOIN qualifications ON users.id = qualifications.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```

Or you can separate them:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    subjects,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(subjects, ',', 1) AS subject1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(subjects, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS subject2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(subjects, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS subject3
FROM (
    SELECT
        users.id,
        users.name,
        CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(qualifications.subject SEPARATOR ','), ',,') AS subjects
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN qualifications ON users.id = qualifications.user_id
    GROUP BY users.id, users.name
) AS x
```